# implementing pipeline using fork and pipe

Tags: c, linux, fork, pipe

I need to implement nameless pipes using fork for my OS class but I cant get it to work. Its a simple code and have nothing special in it but I just dont get anything. Im trying to run 
ls -l | wc -l but I get 0 everytime.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h> // for open flags
#include <time.h> // for time measurement
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int pid,status;
int pipefd[2];

void my_exec(char* cmd, char** argv)
{
    pipe(pipefd);     // Fixed
    pid = fork();
    // pipe(pipefd);  // Original

    if(pid==0){
        close(pipefd[0]);
        dup2(pipefd[1],fileno(stdout));
        close(pipefd[1]);
        execvp(cmd, argv);


    }
    else {
        close(pipefd[1]);
        dup2(pipefd[0],fileno(stdin));
        while(wait(&status)!=-1);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        return; 
    }

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    assert(strcmp(argv[argc-1], "-"));

    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-")) {
            argv[i] = NULL;
            my_exec(argv[1], &argv[1]);
            argv = &argv[i];
            argc -= i;
            i = 0;
        }

    }

    char* args[argc];
    args[argc-1] = NULL;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        args[i-1] = argv[i];

    }

    if (execvp(args[0], args) == -1)
        perror("execvp failed");
    return;
}
```

btw the input for the command Im trying is ls -l - wc -l (instead of | type -)

OK Duck solved it: i should create the pipe before the fork, updated.

Comment: You are not "implementing pipes".  You are using pipes and forking to create a pipeline.  Perhaps this is semantic quibbling, but "implementing pipes using fork" is a very odd expression.

Comment: For starters create the pipes before the `fork`.

Comment: Side note: Waiting for the child to terminate will not work if the child is blocked because it writes too much to the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest problem is that you have the fork in front of the pipe.  This will effectively have each branch of the fork call `pipe()` and thus you'll end up with two different pipefd sets, not the same set.  Reverse the calling order of the fork() and pipe() and then you're file descriptors in each fork will be the same.

As a side note, you can do a `printf()` for debugging inside each of the `if()` statement components to make sure you're never seeing more than two descriptor numbers total.